Problems in deriving the upper bound of quantum noise induced barren plateau phenomenon
I have got the main ideas of paper Noise-Induced Barren Plateaus in Variational Quantum Algorithms, but the process of proving the theorem 1 in supplementary note 2 has got me really confusing. Especially in writting the upper bound of this equility, I really have no ideas on what j and j' means in this content, I hope someone can help me by writing this derivation more clearly.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
